# Localization in DNN with what

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I wanted to localize my Dotnetnuke to German Language.. any package or give me a clue to do it,So it would be better any package direct installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Languages in Admin Panel.and use Delidoft package.It's easy